# bash install scripts: answer navigation doesn't work (Windows, Quasar)

Tags: bash

platform: Windows 10, using bash terminal

This is crazy, but...
when I run install scripts in bash that that present command line based menu choices, the arrow keys (and others) often don't work for navigating the potential answers!  This happens on almost all of these types of scripts, but the Vue and Quasar scripts definitely don't work.  The hints say to use arrow keys, but no dice.  Enter works to select, and sometimes the space bar works to move through choices, but not always.  This is surprisingly terrible in terms of effects - I  can't choose the options to install with and find myself blocked looking for workarounds.

What in heck is going on?

Comment: Bash scripts _usually_ don't support arrow keys for "navigating potential answers". I'm not familiar with Vue or Quasar, but _in general_ this is not a widely-supported feature: bash's support for fancy terminal features is limited to the readline library it uses for providing editing features.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include enough information that the problem can be replicated using only the content of the question -- we shouldn't need to go off-site to find the install script for Vue or Quasar and dig through it to figure out whether and how this is _supposed_ to be working.

Comment: (Now, if these "install scripts" are actually written in javascript, rather than bash, and are using a javascript curses library, _that_ would make some sense... but it would also be something that's not at all a bash question; bash can't control how a program it started chooses to interact with the terminal)

Comment: (...the other way scripts often present menus to the user and read the answers given is using a tool like `dialog` and its many competitors, but again, those are separate programs written in a non-bash language doing the job of presenting the menu and reading its answers; bash itself plays no part beyond starting the program that displays the menu and reading that program's output after it's finished running).

Comment: Sorry, but a bad user experience isn't really on-topic for StackOverflow, unless you're the unfortunate coder of these problematic installers and then you'd need to share an [mcve]. Voting to close. Please reread [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ,   [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  ,  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [mcve] . Good luck.

Comment: please switch your keyboard to US

Comment: @TachibanaShin my keyboard is already set to US.

Comment: @shellter  this isn't really what I'd call a "bad user experience" - it's a bug somewhere that is causing a widely used install script to break.  I will reread the recommended guidelines.\

Comment: Also, suddenly the Quasar install script started working.  All I did was verify that bash text editor nano worked with arrow keys.  Then when I tried the install script again, arrow keys worked.  Note: I have seem this problem a number of times but have no idea what causes it.  I didn't even reboot anywhere along the way.